# Достающий задачу из порта завершения GetQueuedCompletionStatus - глючит?

Tags: c++, c, winsock, winsock2, iocp

Наблюдаю не совсем понятную для себя ситуацию:

1)Создаю порт завершения.

2)Создаю функцию обработки порта завершения.

3)Создаю сокет.

4)Связываю сокет с портом.

5)Вызываю WSASend и отправляю на удаленный сервер заведомо некорректное сообщение - просто "A".

Далее функция обработки ловит и достает из порта завершения с помощью GetQueuedCompletionStatus "сообщение" о готовой задаче, то есть мое сообщение в 1 байт отправилось:

//Условно:

```
void My_func_for_IOCP(...)
{
 
while (1)
{
 
my_BOOL_GetQueuedCompletionStatus = GetQueuedCompletionStatus(iocp, &my_DWORD, &my_CompletionKey, &my_WSAOVERLAPPED, INFINITE);
 
 
if (my_BOOL_GetQueuedCompletionStatus == TRUE)       
{
 
std::cout << "my_DWORD:" << my_DWORD <<std::endl;  //Выводится информация о том, сколько байт доступно для чтения/или сколько отправлено.
 
 
std::cout << std::endl << my_WSABUF_WSARecv.buf << std::endl;
 
 
my_WSARecv = WSARecv(my_SOCKET, &my_WSABUF_WSARecv, 1, NULL, &my_flag, &my_WSAOVERLAPPED_WSARecv, NULL);
 
}
}
```

После того, как задача из порта завершения была извлечена:

-вызываю функцию чтения WSARecv.

-После этого, в порт завершения должна поступить по мере готовности задача на чтение.

-Поэтому цикл while повторяется, соответвенно вызывается GetQueuedCompletionStatus и как в очереди появляется готовая задача - код выполнится далее...

-На консоль выводится информация о том, сколько байт доступно для чтения и я читаю из my_WSABUF_WSARecv..buf - кол-во байт соответвует действительности, сообщение от сервера такое:

> HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request Server: nginx Date: Thu, 08 Jul 2021 16:55:06
> GMT Content-Type: text/html Content-Length: 166 Connection: close
>
> 400 Bad Request
>
> ## 400 Bad Request
>
> ---
>
> nginx

И вроде бы все хорошо, НО ситуация следующая: после того, как я прочитал пришедшее сообщение, в цикле вызывается опять функция WSARecv(это не правильно, просто так получилось) - и вот тут непонятки:

-Во первых судя по сообщению от сервера: Connection: close - сокет должен быть закрыт, НО функция WSARecv вызванная второй раз - не выдает ошибок, напротив она завершается успешно!

-И второе, WSARecv - завершилась успешно, цикл опять перешел к выполнению функции GetQueuedCompletionStatus и ТАМ откуда то была готовая задача!! Но при этом когда я смотрю, сколько байт готово по этой задаче:

```
std::cout << "my_DWORD:" << my_DWORD <<std::endl;
```

my_DWORD - показывает ноль.

Почему GetQueuedCompletionStatus - срабатывает ??? А не спит в ожидании ?

Answer (score 0):

Сервер может закрыть TCP-соединение на своей стороне двумя способами: послав TCP-пакет с флагом FIN (изящное закрытие) или с флагом RST (грубый сброс соединения). Если сокет прислал TCP-пакет с флагом FIN, то на уровне сокетов это будет выглядеть как завершение функций чтения (в т.ч. WSARecv) с результатом 0 байт. При использовании iocp GetQueuedCompletionStatus в такой ситуации возвращает true и 0 байт. Скорее всего, в Вашем случае происходит именно это. (Кстати, сокет при этом ещё жив. Послав FIN, сервер сообщает, что он больше ничего присылать не будет. Читать из сокета больше нельзя. Но чисто технически Вы можете в этот сокет писать, пока сами не отправили FIN или RST. Правда, если используется протокол HTTP с закрытием соединения после запроса, то писать в такой сокет бессмысленно. Сервер не будет читать. Поэтому такой сокет остаётся только закрыть.)

Comment: Plinto, спасибо, но проблема в том, что это происходит не один раз, а бесконечно в цикле. То есть после каждого WSARecv в очередь добавляется задача до бесконечности, хотя читать уже нечего.

Comment: @Optimus1 Так Вы не запускайте очередную операцию чтения после того как прочитали 0 байт. А лучше всего закройте TCP-соединение, а потом сокет надо уничтожить.

Comment: Plinto, это то сделать не проблема, но меня интересует именно почему GetQueuedCompletionStatus глючит и помещает задачу и достает готовую задачу по чтению 0 байт?

Comment: @Optimus1 Если был получен FIN, то GetQueuedCompletionStatus всегда возвращает true и 0 байт. Это его нормальное поведение, он так задуман. Интереснее, почему в порт помещается новая задача при вызове WSARecv. Вы проверяли, какой код возвращает эта функция при вызовах после закрытия?

Comment: @Optimus1 Весьма вероятно, что WSARecv возвращает что-то типа WSAEDISCON.

Comment: Plinto, второй вызов WSARecv после того, как я закрыл сокет после первого вызова - дает ошибку SOCKET_ERROR, а WSAGETLASERROR == 1038 (WSAENOTSOCK)

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/127345/discussion-between-yury-plinto-and-optimus1).