# GetQueuedCompletionStatus и нулевые байты приема WSARecv

Tags: c++, c, winapi, winsock, winsock2

Позвольте задать вопрос в продолжении темы:[Достающий задачу из порта завершения GetQueuedCompletionStatus - глючит?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1303388/%D0%94%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%8E%D1%89%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%87%D1%83-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B0-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-getqueuedcompletionstatus-%D0%B3%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82/1303398?noredirect=1#comment2300450_1303398)

Суть такая:

Предположим я делаю запрос на сервер, который условно раз в час выдает данные о температуре.
Соответвенно я использую WSASend, WSARecv и порты завершения Windows.

И проблемка такая:

1. Условно я отправил с помощью WSASend() сообщение на сервер с условным запросом, что я готов получать данные.
2. С помощью GetQueuedCompletionStatus() достаю "готовый пакет завершения" говорящий о том, что WSASend успешно завершился.
3. Теперь вызываю WSARecv() на чтение данных, которые должен отправить удаленный сервер.
4. С помощью GetQueuedCompletionStatus() достаю "готовый пакет завершения" говорящий о том, что данные с сервера получены и записаны в предоставленный буфер.

   И вроде бы все нормально. Но, в следующий час или в любой другой произвольный момент времени - мне нужно получить новую порцию данных о температуре, сокет естественно не закрывается, а поддерживается соединение keep-alive. То есть:
5. Я опять вызываю WSARecv() на чтение, и запускаю GetQueuedCompletionStatus() - ожидая, следующей порции данных с сервера, НО из за проблемы описанной в указанной в самом начале темы - GetQueuedCompletionStatus() сразу же достанет "готовый пакет завершения" с нулевым кол-вом байт. И так бесконечно и непрерывно.

В итоге получается, что следующая порция данных с сервера условно придёт через час и весь этот часть в цикле непрерывно будет крутится вызов GetQueuedCompletionStatus() - возвращая информацию о том, что получено 0 байт.

И как тут быть непонятно.

Comment: дык, как в прошлый раз и ответили, это, скорей всего, говорит о том что сервер закрыл соединение... это нужно отдельно обрабатывать...

Comment: @Fat-Zer, а если бы не закрыл, то таких пакетов по 0 байт не было бы ?

Comment: почти наверняка — нет (хотя я не могу с абсолютной уверенностью авторитетно утвержать, что в winsock2 это должно работать именно так), но, как правило, для потоковых сокетов получение буфера нулевого размера — признак корректного закрытия соединения второй стороной...

Comment: @Fat-Zer, да похоже Вы правы, сейчас проверил на сервере с параметром keep-alive, нулевых пакетов нет. Спасибо!